# Can one "fold" part of the paragraphs in LyX

Tags: lyx, code-folding

By "folding", I mean condense some part of the codes, and by one click , you can unfold them.

Comment: This sort of thing is just outside the remit of what can be done with PDFs or similar formats. I doubt LaTeX or friends can help you.

Comment: I don't think the question is about folding in the resulting pdf.  I believe it is about folding in the editor. LyX does have some folding, you can for example fold notes, ERT, tables and other inserts.  However, general folding is not, AFAIK, implemented at the moment.  It is on the wishlist (http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/FeaturePoll2), though.

Comment: This is usually called a 'flexible outliner', and is something that a lot of TeX-friendly editors have on their wish-lists. I guess it's hard to do :-)

Comment: @JanHlavacek — you should write this as an actual answer `:)`

Comment: ORG mode in emacs effectively does this. So I'm sure you could modify the code there to work in LaTeX mode... But that's not very helpful if the question was about LyX

Comment: Please register on this site otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 11):

While LyX has not yet "traditional" functionality for general editor folding, it can relatively easy be simulated by using *LyX branches*. As branches are insets, they can be folded within LyX. (By activating/deactivating them, you could even fold them in the output, but that is another story.)

[image]

To fold some content, just select it and then choose *Insert->Branch* from the menu. If you do this the first time, you have to create the respective branch (e.g., "Folded"); afterwards, you can just put more content into the "Folded" branch. For quick access, it is possible and recommended to bind this function to a keyboard shortcut.

Note that a new branch is *deactivated* by default, which means that its content will not appear in the output. You can change this by right-clicking on the inset.

Comment: Very handy! Could you specify which function to bind to a keyboard shortcut? Is it possible to create a function that inserts a specific branch? I'd love to be able to mark text, press shortcut and then have it in the designated branch (as it is possible with other insets, like footnote, comment, etc.)

Comment: @Rasmus: At times it is a bit tricky to figure out what LyX commands one actually has to bind to a shortcut to achieve the desired behavior. However, you can investigate it! See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22938/shortcut-for-vertical-space-in-lyx/22956#22956 for a general approach.

Comment: The suggestion worked admirably. The function is 'branch-insert Name-of-Branch' .

Comment: This thread is very old. I wonder if there has been any updates on this? Native support for folding would be very nice.

Comment: @becko: Good point, but unfortunately the release notes of LyX 2.3.x do not show anything new related to folding: https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX23

Answer (score 7):

OK, since this have remained unanswered for a while, I will retype my comment here. LyX does have some folding, you can for example fold notes, ERT, tables and other inserts. However, general folding is not implemented at the moment. It is on the [wishlist](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/FeaturePoll2).

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to (ab)using branches, one can easily define a custom inset by adding the following to *Document > Settings > Local Layout*:

```
InsetLayout Flex:Foldable          # Define a new "flex" inset called "Foldable"
  LyxType         custom           # Add to Insert > Custom Insets
  LatexType       none             # Export contents to latex as-is, ignoring the wrapper.
  Decoration      minimalistic     # Do not show a label, only the outer box, when not folded.
  ContentAsLabel  true             # When folded show truncated contents as label.
End
```

### Usage

The inset can be inserted from the menu entry *Insert > Custom Insets > Foldable* of by typing `M-x flex-insert Foldable`.

For multi-file documents, the Local Layout has to be manually replicated across all files.