# Create a keyboard shortcut for changing listing placement in LyX

Tags: lyx

From inline to float and vice versa. Is it possible? I don't see anything immediately obvious in [LyX Functions](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyxFunctions).

Comment: The LFUN or even sequence of LFUNs to bind a certain GUI functionality to a shortcut is often not obvious in LyX. In my answer to [Shortcut for “vertical space” in LyX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22938/shortcut-for-vertical-space-in-lyx/22956#22956) I have described how to determine the LFUNs, which probably would help in your case as well.

Comment: `-dbg action` doesn't seem to work in the Windows LyX version, unfortunately :( I will try it tomorrow under Linux.

Comment: Alexey, are your referring to `-dbg action` in particular or on how to run `lyx.exe` from a `CMD` console in Windows in general? I am pretty sure that it works; on Windows it can however be a bit difficult to locate the LyX binary and run it from a console window.

Comment: I have run it from console window with no problems, but it doesn't recognize the `-dbg action` option: the LyX window appears, but I immediately get a new prompt in `cmd.exe`. For that matter, `lyx -help` and `lyx -version` don't work either.

Comment: IIRC, under Windows the true command line version is called `lyxc.exe`, whereas `lyx.exe` is a wrapper around it that "hides" the console windows. So maybe `lyxc --help` will give you any insights.

Comment: As written, this is rather vague, so I've closed as 'not a real question'.