# Implement shortcut in LyX for Itemize environment nested under Lemma

Tags: lyx, itemize

I want to implement a shortcut in LyX that I can use to insert my own itemize environment.

The reason for implementing is the following: because when you want to add a itemize environment the Lemma environment also changes, too. Anybody using LyX knows how annoying that gets.

[image: itemize]

At best I just press `Ctrl+Alt+i` and the environment pops up.

Comment: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=25402&p=86510#p86510

Comment: What makes the environment "your own"? Would you be satisfied with a shortcut for the normal itemize environment?

Comment: You can have a lot of control over things like this. For creating the shortcut, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531 . For creating your own itemize environment, see Help > Customization. You probably want to work off of the already implemented itemize layout (which is just an external text file, it is not in the C++ code of LyX). It is defined in stdlists.inc

Answer (score 1):

In inserting the Itemize environment, you jump out of the Lemma environment. Yep, that can be annoying.

To push the Itemize environment (or other) into the above environment (Lemma, in this case), press `Tab` while in your itemized list.

To create a shortcut that does this for you in one go, go to `Tools > Preferences > Shortcuts > New` and insert as function

```
command-sequence layout Itemize; command-alternatives completion-accept;cell-forward;tab-insert;depth-increment;outline-in
```

Assign it a shortcut and you're good to go!

**ProTip:** I created the function by 1) knowing that one can use the `command-sequence` in specifying shortcuts -- it is extremely powerful ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48060/12558)). 2) I knew that you had to use `Tab` to push environments -- I'm pretty sure I found that in the LyX documentation. 3) Finally, I looked up what functions `Tab` and `shortcut to insert Itemize` executed in the defined shortcuts, and composed the using `command-sequence`.

I hope this answers your question. In any case, thank you for the "soduko" :)