# Lyx : Name of function : Page Break

Tags: lyx

I'm trying to find the name of the function :
Insert -> formatting -> Page Break

So i can set it as a shortcut from preferences ->Editing->shortcuts->new.
But in order to do that i need the function name, and i can't seem to find it online.

Anyone knows?

Comment: `\newpage`. is that what youre looking for?

Comment: Nope. When you try to make a new shortcut it's asks for the function name. I tried 'newpage' and '\newpage' both were invalid names

Comment: Have you tried `\clearpage`?

Comment: Not working as well.

Comment: So, you are trying to get a keyboard shortcut for a TeX macro, is that right? LyX is telling you that `\newpage` and `\clearpage` are invalid names?

Comment: I'm not sure what does a TeX macro means. I re edit my question to show were the problem occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the menubar and press

```
Tools | Preferences | Editing | Shortcuts
```

In the window that has popped up, enter `newpage` in the field called *Show key-binding containing*. In the window below, you will see a function called

```
newpage-insert
```

Highlight this and press *Modify*. In the window that pops up, you can enter your favorite shortcut (I have used `Alt+Shift+N`).

Press *Apply* first and then *Save*, and you should be done.

Works for me under Linux with LyX 2.0.4.

Comment: Great Thanks! Any chance you know the function name for : vertical space?

Comment: Sorry I don't but maybe [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22938/shortcut-for-vertical-space-in-lyx) could give you some ideas