# LyX user interface; adding toolbar icon for unformatted tex

Tags: lyx, editors

I am a heavy user of LyX 2.0 and I want to to add useful shortcuts to help me in my work. I tend to copy and paste a lot of text from PDFs or the web or even some old work written in MS Word. A shortcut for pasting unformatted text would be useful in this case. I tried to create a toolbar icon in a similar way to the example below in my custom `toolbar.inc`.

```
Item "Bold" "font-bold"
```

I wonder if there is something similar to the above command to that of the unformatted text.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22956/3751 for an approach to find out the LFUNs that need to be bound to a keyboard shortcut or toolbar icon.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
clipboard-paste-simple
```

There are a number of ways for you to figure out what the command is:

1. Search through Help > LyX Functions.
2. Go to View > Messages. With that window open, do what you do graphically to reproduce the command you want (in this case Edit > Paste Special > Unformatted Text).
3. If 2. doesn't work, go to "settings" in the Messages box and add "User commands". Alternatively, start LyX from the command line with `-dbg action`.
4. go to your library folder (find this out in Help > About) and go to ui/stdmenus.inc and search for "Unformatted Text". There you will see the corresponding command.

Comment: Answer above Works perfectly.Many thanks. Katy.