# The image through the command buffer

Tags: lyx

Please tell me how to insert images via specific LyX command buffer? In messages after such operation catches the eye the following passage:

```
..\..\..\..\src\frontends\qt4\GuiApplication.cpp (1266): cmd: action: 224 [inset-apply] arg: 'graphics filename 1.eps
\end_inset
' x: 0 y: 0
..\..\src\BufferView.cpp (1207): BufferView::dispatch: cmd: action: 224 [inset-apply] arg: 'graphics filename 1.eps
\end_inset
' x: 0 y: 0
..\..\..\..\src\frontends\qt4\GuiApplication.cpp (1266): cmd: action: 225 [inset-insert] arg: 'graphics filename 1.eps
\end_inset
' x: 0 y: 0
..\..\src\BufferView.cpp (1207): BufferView::dispatch: cmd: action: 225 [inset-insert] arg: 'graphics filename 1.eps
\end_inset
' x: 0 y: 0
```

However, the implementation of such commands (without square brackets) in the command buffer does not give the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Open the command buffer with alt+x or View > Toolbars > Command Buffer.

Then run the following command:

```
inset-apply graphics filename 1.eps
```

Comment: scottkosty, thank you very much, this is what you need. Please tell me how you got this command? Or just you know?

Comment: I know [this way] [1], but in this case nothing gave.

  [1]:[https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22938/shortcut-for-vertical-space-in-lyx]

Comment: @mathem actually I just used the output that you had in your question (good job for posting it). You just have to get used to reading the output. `inset-apply` is the name of the LFUN, and the "arguments" (what follows the LFUN) is what is enclosed inside the single quotes.

Comment: the name of the LFUN is understandable, but it has been placed within square brackets, that was confusing. In the arguments generally present \end_inset and try to guess what to do.

Comment: @scottkoste, using your tips I wrote a .js file, through which you can insert graphics in LyX, without taking your hands off the keyboard. Now I want to do the same for navigating large images. Insert this picture the standard way generates the following message: [inset-apply] arg: ' wrap Wrap figure lines placement 0 r 0in overhang
width% 50col "' x: 0 y: 0. Seemingly, using your logic, the proposed team must be: inset-apply wrap Wrap figure lines placement 0 r overhang 0in width "50col% ".

Comment: However, run the following command in the command buffer has no action, while not causing the error. Maybe you try to bring the team to a healthy state?

Comment: @mathem unfortunately I don't have any time to look at this. Perhaps start a new question and hopefully someone can take a look? Or send an email to the lyx-users list.

Comment: scottkosty, I cannot punish the duplication issue?

Comment: @mathem if you're worried about cross-posting, don't worry. On lyx-users just link to your post on tex.se. And on tex.se, link to your post on lyx-users (e.g., use mail archive link).