# Toggle Hide/Show cites, footnotes etc

Tags: editors, sublime-text

It annoys a lot, if my written text has lots of footnotes or cites, so a quick reading and writing in same editor ( not in pdf, as you may point out) is a tough matter. I wonder if there is any possiblity to hide or at least shorten Cites, footnotes, references in writing or reading mode in Sublime or other editor for MAC

Edit:

I found out that it is possible manually fold selected lines with (mac) cmd + alt + [ . But automated process whould be perfect

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52216/7883 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117073/7883 for folding in Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

[LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) may be a simple editor alternative with folding of footnotes etc. for you.

Comment: Not natively. You'll have to insert it as a *branch*, right? See [Can one “fold” part of the paragraphs in LyX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5027/5764).

Comment: LyX isn't really a LaTeX editor. @Werner Yes, natively just click on the box where it says e.g. *foot 1*. Edit: Sorry, that's just footnotes.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: So there is no cold-folding for footnotes?

Comment: @Werner Yes footnotes can be folded, but not citations, as far as I could see.

Comment: maybe off-topic, but it doesn't support retina displays and therefore looks awful (pixelated)